# In cake php 3 we can use an contoller with is an two caps

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In cake php 3 it is possible to use an controller in different formate.like

HomeDudeController  then how we use in url ? /homedude is this correct. without change in routers

and if can use the controller quick_search like this

Answer (score 1):

Please find enclosed here with link for conventions in cakephp 3 
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html

For Routing 
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html

CakePHP 3 has the best documentation please go through this.

Reach back if you have any issues.